# Library Link Errors when Making a Python C Extension

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

For the last several days I have attempted to create a C extension for Python, but have run into error LNK2001: typically trivial, but I have yet to figure out the cause.

First, here's the relevant C code:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "visa.h" /* external VISA library */
#include "visatype.h" 

...

/*Static variables*/
static ViSession defaultRM;
static ViSession instr;
static ViStatus status;
static ViUInt32 retCount;
static ViUInt32 writeCount;

...

/*Method table for the Python interpreter.
static PyMethodDef VISAIO_Methods[] = {
    {"openMainframe", VISAIO_openMainframe, METH_NOARGS, "Open a VISA session with the mainframe."},
    {"sendMsg", VISAIO_sendMsg, METH_VARARGS, "Send a message to the specified port. 0 = mainframe. (int port, char* message)"},
    {"readMsg", VISAIO_readMsg, METH_VARARGS, "Return a message of specified length from the buffer of the specified port. 0 = mainframe. (int port, char* message, int maxLength)"},
    {"closeMainFrame", VISAIO_closeMainframe, METH_NOARGS, "Close the VISA session."}
};

/*Structure passed to Python module initializer. Arguments are unexplained in documentation, but two are obvious.*/
static struct PyModuleDef VISAIOmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "VISAIO",
    NULL,
    -1,
    VISAIO_Methods
};

/*Initializes the module for use by the Python program.*/
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_VISAIO(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&VISAIOmodule);
}
```

and Python:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('VISAIO',
                depends = ['visa32.lib'],
                include_dirs = ['Include'],
                libraries = ['visa32'],
                sources = ['VISAIOmodule.c'],)

setup (name = 'VISAIO',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This handles low-level IO with the VISA library.',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

I run the Python file using the command `python setup.py build`
and get the following:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'VISAIO' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
-IInclude "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /TcVISAIOmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\VISAIOmodule.obj
VISAIOmodule.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\libs" 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\PCbuild\win32" 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" visa32.lib 
/EXPORT:PyInit_VISAIO build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\VISAIOmodule.obj 
/OUT:build\lib.win32-3.5\VISAIO.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\VISAIO.cp35-win32.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\VISAIO.cp35-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\VISAIO.cp35-win32.exp
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viSetAttribute@12
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viOpenDefaultRM@4
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viWrite@16
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viClose@4
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viOpen@20
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viRead@16
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viClear@4
VISAIOmodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _viGetAttribute@12
build\lib.win32-3.5\VISAIO.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

The result of which is a compiled VISAIOmodule.obj file, which indicates to me that the C compiler correctly linked the VISA library to the source code. However, when I followed [this alternative method](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C#Building_the_extension_module_with_GCC_for_Microsoft_Windows) to the letter, gcc told me `VISAIOmodule.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized.`

When the program proceeds to create the Python library, link errors are thrown. I have made absolutely certain that the library in question is in all of the standard search directories as well as my specified one. What is going on?

Comment: `VISAIOmodule.obj` is no indication of successful linking, only compiling. Are you sure everything is either 32bit or 64bit, since mixing does not work?

Comment: I have vc2015 32 and 64 bit, as well as Python 3.5 32 and 64 bit. As far as I know, the library I'm using comes only in 32 bit.  Could there be any incompatibility I haven't mentioned? EDIT: It looks like both Python and vc are in 32 bit mode based on the command prompt output.